# modify matrix via a void function inside a function

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, linear-algebra

I have dynamically allocated a matrix inside my main function. I want to find the uppertriangular of the matrix. I am using a guasselemination algorithm. The function name is Uppertriangle. The void function takes in three arguments:

```
void Uppertriangle(double** A, double *B, int n)
```

I want to return the modified matrix A with my modified vector B inside the function SolveUppertriangle.

```
void SolveUpperTriangle(double **A, double *B,int size){
    ReadMatrix(A,size); //Original matrix printed
    UpperTriangle(A,B,size); //Prints out modified A 
    ReadMatrix(A,size);  //Still prints out the Original Matrix

}
```

When I print out the matrix inside UpperTriangle the matrix is modified correctly, although the function inside another function does not effect the allocated matrix. I could choose to put all the code of UpperTriangle inside SolveUpperTriangle, and that would solve the problem. But I want to figure out why the matrix is not changed.

```
int main(){
 "here allocating matrix"

SolveUpperTriangular(A,B,n);
}
```

The original A matrix

```
4   4   2   
4   5   3   
2   3   3
```

The modified uppertriangular matrix printed inside Uppertriangle.

```
4   5   3   
0   -1  -1  
0   0   1.2
```

The original matrix printed out again.

```
4   4   2   
4   5   3   
2   3   3
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it **is** changed. Please post a minimal, complete example so we can see what you're seeing.

Comment: Ok, I in a moment, will print out the output inside UpperTriangle and inside SolveUpperTriangle. These are different.

Comment: It's not that I don't believe you, you don't need to show the values of the matrix. What you need to show is the code that created and modified that matrix. How are we supposed to pin-point at the error if you don't show us what you're doing? Your `UpperTriangle` function declaration looks OK. If you modify `A` inside there then you'll be modifying the caller's matrix. Your error is probably inside that function. -- Please read about [how to create a minimal compete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).